# How can i refresh the UI using Component Art Callback in C# Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

once the page is loaded if we need to add something on the UI then how we will do it by using callback without loading the whole page again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UpdatePanel to do this i.e. without refreshing your whole page it can change components of your page.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelMain" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:Button ID="BtnClick" runat="server" OnClick="BtnClick_Click"  />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnClick" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
```

Now you will get call in code behind whenever "BtnClick" button is clicked. There you can write your code.

```
 protected void BtnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Your logic
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but can we do the same thing with callback?